# WiX Heat: sort order of components

Tags: sorting, wix

I want to be able to compare the WXS file - generated by heat - with the previous version so that I can verify the changes.

But I can't find any logic behind the component order. The generated components are neither sorted by Id nor by directory name. And always when I regenerate my WXS files and some files have been added, the order is totally different, which makes the comparation very difficult.

Is there any way to control the sort order? Ideal would be, if the components would be sorted by the source of inner file node. But any constant order would be good enough for me.

E.g. for the following example, it would be great, when the components are sorted by file source. I.E. AutoMapper before Log4Net

```
<Component Id="cmpB83..." Directory="DIR.MYDIR" Guid="{2A49...}">
    <File Id="filA272..." KeyPath="yes" source="$(var.MYVAR)\AutoMapper.xml" />
</Component>
<Component Id="cmp445..." Directory="DIR.MYDIR" Guid="{1C34...}">
    <File Id="filB356..." KeyPath="yes" source="$(var.MYVAR)\Log4Net.xml" />
</Component>
```

I start heat with following parameters:

`heat.exe dir MYDIR -gg -dr DIR.MYDIR -srd -sreg -ke -cg compGroup.MYGROUP -var var.MYVAR -out ..\MYOUTPUT.wxs`

I use WiX 3.11.

Comment: While XML elements do have an order, as you suggest I don't think that order matters to WIX or Windows installer. You could sort them yourself with each run of heat. One way of doing that would be to pass an XSLT to heat that would apply for you. (I hope someone gives an answer that makes this moot.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since there is no answer since two years, I will show what I have done:

I use this code to re-order the components via "source" in the generated file and store it to a copy:

```
XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Load(filename);

XElement componentsFragment = xdoc.Root.Elements().ElementAt(1);
XElement componentGroup = componentsFragment.Elements().ElementAt(0);
List<XElement> components = componentGroup.Elements().ToList();
List<XElement> sortedComponents = components.OrderBy(one =>   one.Elements().ElementAt(0).Attribute("Source").Value).ToList();

componentGroup.RemoveNodes();
foreach (XElement component in sortedComponents)
{
  componentGroup.Add(component);
}

xdoc.Save(resultFilename);
```